# Google Form trigger

Tags: triggers

I set the trigger to submit the spreadsheet_form through the app script, but the trigger does not work normally
Are there any issues with setting up Google Form responses and Apps script triggers?
It's a sudden problem since this morning, and there's a lot of inconvenience
Ask if it is a confirmed problem and how to take action, and do the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).